# Serialize Map object with jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dictionary, serialization

[This is first question on SO, so apologize me for any mistake]

I'm trying to save a Map, like the one below, in a cookie.

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("k1", {
    a1: "...",
    a2: "...",
    a3: "..."
});
```

For this, I have to format as JSON. I tried many methods, like:

```
$.toJSON(myMap)
$.param(myMap)
JSON.stringify(myMap)
```

But none of them seems to work...

So, I did this:

```
var serial = [];
myMap.forEach(function(value){
    serial.push(value);
});
var result = $.toJSON(serial)
```

(Having to reconstruct the key on decoding the JSON...)

There is a better way to serialize a Map object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not exactly a typical "stringify", but you can use the spread operator combined with `JSON.stringify()`, that will give you an array...

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("k1", { a1: "...", a2: "...", a3: "..." });
myMap.set("k2", { b1: "...", b2: "...", b3: "..." });

var myJSON = JSON.stringify([...myMap]);
alert(myJSON);
```

This will give you...

```
[["k1",{"a1":"...","a2":"...","a3":"..."}],["k2",{"b1":"...","b2":"...","b3":"..."}]]
```

And to convert it to Map again...

```
var recoveredMap = new Map(JSON.parse(myJSON));
```

Comment: This works great, but is not supported by older Browsers.  Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

While spread operator is good if you want to stringify immediate maps, you'll face problems if they are nested within any data structures.

Both JSON.stringify and JSON.parse support callback functions:

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
JSON.parse(text[, reviver])
```

So you can write functions such as:

```
function replacer (key, value){
    if (value.__proto__ == Map.prototype) {
        return {
            _type: "map",
            map: [...value],
        }
    } else return value;
}

function reviver (key, value){
    if (value._type == "map") return new Map(value.map);
    else return value;
}
```

Now you can easily stringify/parse maps no matter how deep they are nested:

```
let obj = {
    map: new Map([
        [1, new Map([
            [1,2],
            [3,4],
        ])],
        [2,3],
    ]),
};
console.log(obj);
let str = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer);
console.log(str);
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
console.log(JSON.parse(str, reviver));
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) to convert your `Map` into an array

```js
// initialize the map
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("k1", {
  a1: "...",
  a2: "...",
  a3: "..."
});
myMap.set("k2", {
  a1: "...",
  a2: "...",
  a3: "..."
});


// serialize the map by converting it to an array
var mapAsArray = Array.from(myMap);
console.log('Map as array ',mapAsArray);

var serializedMap = JSON.stringify(mapAsArray);
console.log(serializedMap)

// deserialize into a new map
var map = new Map(JSON.parse(serializedMap))
console.log(map.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a new JS feature - Object.fromEntries. It can parse a map into an object

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj))
const objectCopy = Object.fromEntries(map)
```

Compatibility is ok (Chrome, FF, Safari) and a polyfill exists. We can also expect compatibility to spread to all browsers since fromEntries is a "stage 4" proposal (approved).
See Compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)