# How to convert MongooseMap to JSON object to send it from Node js to React?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, mongoose

In mongoose, there is [Map data type](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps) that allows to store arbitrary keys.
I understand that to get and set values I should use `get` and `set` methods. However, when I send an object to frontend, Nodejs sends just empty JSON object. 
Is there a way to automatically convert Mongoose object, that has Map type, into JSON object to send over the network, without extracting every key with `get` on the backend?

My model:

```
var  mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = require('./user');
var Post = require('./post');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const DescriptionSchema = new Schema({
    timeStamp: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    postid: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Post'},
    userid: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    dstrings:{
        type: Map,
        of: String// key value
      }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Description', DescriptionSchema);
```

My controller:

```
// '/v1/description/add'
    api.post('/add', authenticate,(req, res) => {
        let description = new Description({         
            postid: ObjectId(req.body.postid),
            userid: ObjectId(req.user.id), 
            dstrings:req.body.dstrings,

        });
        description.save(function(err, description) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({ message: err });
            } else {
//  description.dstrings is equal to {} on the frontend               
                    res.status(200).json( description );
                }
            });  
        });
```

JSON.stringify didn't work; I checked database, it has the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49399615/7916557).
The problem was in serialization. To serialize an object that contains Map we can pass a function as the second argument to `JSON.stringify` as described in the link above. Then we can deserialize on frontend by passing another function to `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the .json() Syntax But with arguments of the .save() callback function

The save function's callback will accept the following arguments :

- The error
- The document that was saved

Please read the mongoose Prototype.save() docs

The link is [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)

Comment: Good to know. I added the argument, but it did not solve the problem.